# What does the help center mean by "the preparation of miniatures/terrain/etc."?

Tags: support, on-topic, questions

When looking at the help center to see what kind of questions are on-topic, I saw the following:

> - Minature wargames (including the preparation of miniatures/terrain/etc)

What exactly is meant by preparation of miniatures or terrain? I don't believe it implies questions about building or painting miniatures or terrain are on-topic, though I would happily stand corrected.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't think that painting or building miniatures wouldn't be covered by that?

Comment: Because the help center claimed "Board and Card Games Stack Exchange is for expert Q&A from people who like playing, discussing the strategy of, and getting rules clarifications of board games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing board games." This made me believe that the game itself was the focus, not more creative parts such as painting miniatures or terrain. A question like "How can I create a desert base for my miniatures?" just *feels* off-topic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the game is on topic for B&CG.SE (ex. Warhammer), then questions about building and painting miniatures and terrain for those games are also on topic. While most of the questions we get are rules questions we also support questions about other aspects of games and game related topics as well.

Comment: That said, "X is in scope" doesn't necessarily mean "X is likely to get good answers here" and we have to be honest with ourselves that we're likely not the ideal place to come to for mini-painting advice.

Comment: @Cascabel If we know that this is not the best place to ask, wouldn't it be beneficial to redirect people to a good place to ask, such as [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: TBH I feel like this might be a better place than Arts & Crafts... while there's a knee-jerk reaction to assume paint=paint, there's a fair bit of cross-pollination between boardgames and miniatures. Check out any particular board game (that has minis) subreddit and you'll see a ton of threads about painting those minis. And more and more games these days come with minis.